# Description of complete analytic function for $\sqrt{4z-\sqrt[3]{z}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analyticity, analytic-continuation

The problem is to describe all branches and all the curves of analytic continuation of $\sqrt{4z-\sqrt[3]{z}}$.

I started with representing function in a way $\sqrt{4w^3-w}\circ\sqrt[3]{z}$
So, there are 6 branches:

1. $\sqrt{4w^3-w}_{(0)}\circ\sqrt[3]{z}_{(0)}$
2. $\sqrt{4w^3-w}_{(0)}\circ(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\sqrt[3]{z}_{(0)}$
3. $\sqrt{4w^3-w}_{(0)}\circ(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\sqrt[3]{z}_{(0)}$
4. $-\sqrt{4w^3-w}_{(0)}\circ\sqrt[3]{z}_{(0)}$
5. $-\sqrt{4w^3-w}_{(0)}\circ(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\sqrt[3]{z}_{(0)}$
6. $-\sqrt{4w^3-w}_{(0)}\circ(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\sqrt[3]{z}_{(0)}$

Now we need to find out where continuation exists.
Since $\sqrt{4w^3-w}$ is not analytic in 0, we should exclude $w=0, \pm\frac{1}{2}$. This means we have to exclude 0 from all branches, exclude $\pm\frac{1}{8}$ from branches 1,4; $\pm\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^3}$ from 2,5; $\pm\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^3}$ from 3 and 6.
If we have a curve $\gamma$, area of continuation around point $\gamma(t)$ for branches 1 and 4 will be a ball $B(\gamma(t), min(|\gamma(t)|,|\gamma(t)-\frac{1}{8}|,|\gamma(t)+\frac{1}{8}|))$ and analog.

Let's see what is the value of continued function is on the curve $\gamma$. Let's assume $l(z)=ln(|z|)+iarg(z)$
So there should be something like $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{2}l(e^{\frac{1}{3}l(z)})}$, but I don't understand if it's right or should be done other way.

My questions are:

1. Are my thouhts on the problem true or I've chosen absolutely wrong way?
2. How exactly should be written $f(z)$ on the curves of continuation? Or, at least, what can I read to have an enlightenment there.

Comment: I would suggest, as a start, to simplify the notation by getting rid of all those ill-defined radicals: Set $w = \sqrt{4z - \sqrt[3]{z}}$ and rewrite as an implicit equation $(w^2-4z)^3=z$. Now your goal becomes how to describe the solution set of this equation using branch cuts in the $z$-plane and (well-defined) radicals in the various branches.

Comment: Your $(z^{1/3})_0$ is some fixed branch of $z^{1/3}$, say, the principal branch. So some of the branches of $f$ are analytic in a neighborhood of $\pm 1/8$ (note that $(-1/2 \pm i \sqrt 3/2)^3 = 1$). It may be more convenient to write $f(z)$ as $i e^{\pi n i/3} z^{1/6} \sqrt {1 - 4 e^{4 \pi n i/3} z^{2/3}}$, then we can write out explicitly how the branches are permuted when going around the [four](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4328590) branch points of $f$.